# Convert html with applied styles to a string without changes in styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

I want to convert this part of code (`span` tag with styles) into a string and the styles should be applied to the string, so that when I render the string the CSS is activated.

```
let text = <span style=
       {{fontFamily: 'Rubik, sans-serif',
         fontSize: '12px',
         fontWeight: 'normal',
         letterSpacing: '0px',
         color: '#667891'}}>
       {this.props.strings.TotalRecords} {this.state.totalCount}
   </span>
```

I want to pass the variable text to a method and render it with the applied styles in the HTML tags.

Comment: that's why we use react. create it as a component and use it with any other components, reusable components

Comment: I should pass it in currentPageReportTemplate method from PrimeReact DataTable and it accepts only string. This is the problem

Comment: you should mention it in the question, we cant modify what is inside prime datatable. check the document for other options https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/datatable/